# In Word 2021 way to call the open document's Windows 10 Properties dialog

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2021

I want to do this so I can change the name of an open Word document before I close it. I don't want to use Save As because it changes the creation date plus it creates an extra document I have to delete late. Word Backstage properties won't let my change the name. I want something that I can attach to a Ribbon button or create a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: you cannot change the name of a document while it is open in Word

Comment: I know I can't change it while it is open, but I can type the name into the Properties dialog and the save the change after I close the document in Word.

Comment: that makes sense ... perhaps the code should do  the closing of the document and then do the renaming of the document